# Shared pointer references

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

In my code, I use a shared pointer using boost's shared_from_this feature. To keep it short, the shared pointer is shared on similar lines as below:

```
class Q: public enable_shared_from_this<Q>
{
public:

    shared_ptr<Q> f()
    {
        return shared_from_this();
    }
}

int main()
{
    shared_ptr<Q> p(new Q);
    shared_ptr<Q> q = p->f();
    .....
    .....
}
```

When I examine this in gdb:

```
(gdb) p *this
$8 = {
  ....
  <boost::enable_shared_from_this<Q>> = {
    weak_this_ = boost::weak_ptr<Q>(refs=0, weak=2) = {
      px = (Q *) 0xa11f2000
    }
  }
....
}
```

What is the significance of 'refs' and weak' references here? Does refs=0 mean that there are no references to the object?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The control block for a `shared_ptr` holds two reference counts. One is the strong reference count, incremented once for each `shared_ptr` to the object. When it goes to zero the object is destroyed (and deallocated, unless it was allocated with `make_shared`).

The other is the weak reference count, incremented once as long as there are strong references, and again for each `weak_ptr` to the object. When it goes to zero, the control block is destroyed and deallocated.

So yes, in theory, the debugger display `refs=0` means that there are no references to the object. Depending on where your program stopped, however, this sounds unlikely, in the program you show us, `p` lives until the end of `main` and should not give up its strong reference. It could be that the debugger's display is incorrect, especially if you compiled with optimizations.

**Edit:**

A weak count of 2 while refs is 0 means that all strong references are gone (all `shared_ptr` instances referring to the object have been destroyed), but there are 2 `weak_ptr`s remaining; unless the snapshot you're looking at is specifically within the destructor of the last `shared_ptr`, after decrementing the strong count but before decrementing the weak count, in which case it means there's only one weak_ptr left (which could be the one stored in `enable_shared_from_this`, if the snapshot is during your object's destructor).

Are you calling `shared_from_this` in `Q`'s destructor and using the result without checking for null? `shared_from_this` doesn't work in constructors and destructors and always returns null. This could be the cause of the crash and would result in the values you observe.

Comment: I doubt the program stopped in constructor of class Q, before constructing pointer p

Comment: That was just the code snippet to highlight how the shared_ptr is being used. So, yes, in reality there's a lot happening with the shared_ptr in question.

Comment: And the gdb output was from the analysis of the core that was generated in the object's, which is of type shared_ptr, destructor.

Comment: Why is there a difference in the 'refs' and 'weak' in this case? Since it has a weak count of 2, does it mean that the object is a candidate for destruction by the garbage collector?